# JavaScript - The function only execute after set breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jQuery for dynamic attached elements. The **jq-select-ring** button can be multiple on the DOM. Basically, it was attached through an Ajax call.

```
let cKeyTabShift = false;    
$("body").on("keydown", ".jq-select-ring", function (e) {
            if (!isMobileSite) {
                var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (keyCode == 9) {
                    if (e.shiftKey) {
                        cKeyTabShift = true;
                    } else {
                        cKeyTabShift = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    $("body").on("focusout", ".jq-select-ring", function () {
            if (!isMobileSite) {
                const parentIndex = $(this).closest('.flex-item').index();
                const $elmSliders = $(this).closest('.container').find("div[id^='touchCarousel-'][role='tabpanel']");
                const $nextArrow = $(this).closest('.touch-carousel').find('.touchcarousel-next');
                const $prevArrow = $(this).closest('.touch-carousel').find('.touchcarousel-prev');
    
                if (typeof ($elmSliders) != "undefined" && $elmSliders.length > 0) {
                    if ($elmSliders.length > 1) {
                        if (parentIndex == 1 && cKeyTabShift == false) {
                            if (!$nextArrow.hasClass('endArrows')) {
                                $nextArrow.trigger('click');
                            }
                        }
                        if (parentIndex == 0 && cKeyTabShift == true) {
                            if (!$prevArrow.hasClass('endArrows')) {
                                $prevArrow.trigger('click');
                                cKeyTabShift = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The issue is the trigger click is called when I add breakpoint only.

$nextArrow.trigger('click');
$prevArrow.trigger('click');

Comment: It only gets called when adding a breakpoint in your editor or adding a breakpoint in the browser's JavaScript file via the devtools?

Comment: yes, through browser devtools..

Comment: It could be interesting to try to log out the results of your if statements, trigger a focusout event, and then seeing what gets logged to the console to see if you get any hints.

Comment: one more point is... its work for the first tab item... I mean the buttons were on tab items.

Comment: There were multiple tabs.. the example was for one tab items..

Comment: You might not be targeting the right elements then (i.e. your calls to `$(this).clossest(...)` might not yield the correct elements for every focusout event).

Comment: nope... its hitting correct place what i can see from the debugger